# How to detect the right encoding for read.csv?

Tags: r, character-encoding, read.csv

I have this file (http://b7hq6v.alterupload.com/en/) that I want to read in R with `read.csv`. But I am not able to detect the correct encoding. It seems to be a kind of UTF-8. I am using R 2.12.1 on an WindowsXP Machine. 
Any Help?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

First of all [based on more general question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file) it is not possible to detect encoding of file in 100% certainty.

I've struggle this many times and come to non-automatic solution:

Use `iconvlist` to get all possible encodings:

```
codepages <- setNames(iconvlist(), iconvlist())
```

Then read data using each of them

```
x <- lapply(codepages, function(enc) try(read.table("encoding.asc",
                   fileEncoding=enc,
                   nrows=3, header=TRUE, sep="\t"))) # you get lots of errors/warning here
```

Important here is to know structure of file (separator, headers). Set encoding using `fileEncoding` argument. Read only few rows.
Now you could lookup on results:

```
unique(do.call(rbind, sapply(x, dim)))
#        [,1] [,2]
# 437       14    2
# CP1200     3   29
# CP12000    0    1
```

Seems like correct one is that with 3 rows and 29 columns, so lets see them:

```
maybe_ok <- sapply(x, function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(dim(x), c(3,29))))
codepages[maybe_ok]
#    CP1200    UCS-2LE     UTF-16   UTF-16LE      UTF16    UTF16LE 
#  "CP1200"  "UCS-2LE"   "UTF-16" "UTF-16LE"    "UTF16"  "UTF16LE"
```

You could look on data too

```
x[maybe_ok]
```

For your file all this encodings returns identical data (partially because there is some redundancy as you see).

If you don't know specific of your file you need to use `readLines` with some changes in workflow (e.g. you can't use `fileEncoding`, must use `length` instead of `dim`, do more magic to find correct ones).

Comment: I did a quit similar thing for iconvlist(),but with a loop. The crucial thing was the usage of "fileEncoding". I wrongly used "encoding". Thanks for your help.

Comment: I sketched out a similar approach at https://gist.github.com/837414 - I think it's more efficient to load the data once, and then try out different encodings using `iconv`.

Comment: @Marek Nice trick.  At least I know my `read.csv` issue doesn't have to do with `fileEncoding`.

Answer (score 59):

The package `readr`, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/readr.pdf,  includes a function called `guess_encoding` that calculates the probability of a file of being encoded in several encodings:

```
guess_encoding("your_file", n_max = 1000)
```

Comment: This option was very nice and easy to use.

Comment: Sometimes `guess_encoding` fails to deliver definite results, though. Tried it on 11 csv files and 2 of them were equally split between several encodings.

Comment: This solved my issue: i had a massive directory of shapefiles in a mix of encodings that we're detected by st_read on a mac.

 
```{r}
check_encoding <- readr::guess_encoding('shapefile path', n_max = 1000);

if(nrow(check_encoding)>0) {
    tmp_shp <- st_read('shapefile path', options = paste0("ENCODING=", toupper(check_encoding$encoding[[1]])))
} else {
    tmp_shp <- st_read(here::here('shapefile path')
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, you have to figure out what is the encoding of the file, what cannot be done in R (at least as I know). You can use external tools for it e.g. from Perl, python or eg. the `file` utility under Linux/UNIX.

As @ssmit suggested, you have an UTF-16LE (Unicode) encoding here, so load the file with this encoding and use `readLines` to see what you have in the first (e.g.) 10 lines:

```
> f <- file('encoding.asc', open="r", encoding="UTF-16LE")   # UTF-16LE, which is "called" Unicode in Windows
> readLines(f,10)
 [1] "\tFe 2\tZn\tO\tC\tSi\tMn\tP\tS\tAl\tN\tCr\tNi\tMo\tCu\tV\tNb 2\tTi\tB\tZr\tCa\tH\tCo\tMg\tPb 2\tW\tCl\tNa 3\tAr"                                                                                                                          
 [2] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 [3] "0\t0,003128\t3,82E-05\t0,0004196\t0\t0,001869\t0,005836\t0,004463\t0,002861\t0,02148\t0\t0,004768\t0,0003052\t0\t0,0037\t0,0391\t0,06409\t0,1157\t0,004654\t0\t0\t0\t0,00824\t7,63E-05\t0,003891\t0,004501\t0\t0,001335\t0,01175"         
 [4] "0,0005\t0,003265\t3,05E-05\t0,0003662\t0\t0,001709\t0,005798\t0,004395\t0,002808\t0,02155\t0\t0,004578\t0,0002441\t0\t0,003601\t0,03897\t0,06406\t0,1158\t0,0047\t0\t0\t0\t0,008026\t6,10E-05\t0,003876\t0,004425\t0\t0,001343\t0,01157"  
 [5] "0,001\t0,003332\t2,54E-05\t0,0003052\t0\t0,001704\t0,005671\t0,0044\t0,002823\t0,02164\t0\t0,004603\t0,0003306\t0\t0,003611\t0,03886\t0,06406\t0,1159\t0,004705\t0\t0\t0\t0,008036\t5,09E-05\t0,003815\t0,004501\t0\t0,001246\t0,01155"   
 [6] "0,0015\t0,003313\t2,18E-05\t0,0002616\t0\t0,001678\t0,005689\t0,004447\t0,002921\t0,02171\t0\t0,004621\t0,0003488\t0\t0,003597\t0,03889\t0,06404\t0,1158\t0,004752\t0\t0\t0\t0,008022\t4,36E-05\t0,003815\t0,004578\t0\t0,001264\t0,01144"
 [7] "0,002\t0,003313\t2,18E-05\t0,0002834\t0\t0,001591\t0,005646\t0,00436\t0,003008\t0,0218\t0\t0,004643\t0,0003488\t0\t0,003619\t0,03895\t0,06383\t0,1159\t0,004752\t0\t0\t0\t0,008\t4,36E-05\t0,003771\t0,004643\t0\t0,001351\t0,01142"      
 [8] "0,0025\t0,003488\t2,18E-05\t0,000218\t0\t0,001657\t0,00558\t0,004338\t0,002986\t0,02175\t0\t0,004469\t0,0002616\t0\t0,00351\t0,03889\t0,06374\t0,1159\t0,004621\t0\t0\t0\t0,008131\t4,36E-05\t0,003771\t0,004708\t0\t0,001243\t0,01125"   
 [9] "0,003\t0,003619\t0\t0,0001526\t0\t0,001591\t0,005668\t0,004207\t0,00303\t0,02169\t0\t0,00449\t0,0002834\t0\t0,00351\t0,03874\t0,06383\t0,116\t0,004665\t0\t0\t0\t0,007956\t0\t0,003749\t0,004796\t0\t0,001286\t0,01125"                   
[10] "0,0035\t0,003422\t0\t4,36E-05\t0\t0,001482\t0,005711\t0,004185\t0,003292\t0,02156\t0\t0,004665\t0,0003488\t0\t0,003553\t0,03852\t0,06391\t0,1158\t0,004708\t0\t0\t0\t0,007717\t0\t0,003597\t0,004905\t0\t0,00133\t0,01136"
```

From this, it can be seen, that we have a header, and a blank line in the second row (which will be skipped by default using the `read.table` function), the separator is `\t` and the decimal character is `,`.

```
> f <- file('encoding.asc', open="r", encoding="UTF-16LE")
> df <- read.table(f, sep='\t', dec=',', header=TRUE)
```

And see what we have:

```
> head(df)
       X     Fe.2       Zn         O C       Si       Mn        P        S
1 0.0000 0.003128 3.82e-05 0.0004196 0 0.001869 0.005836 0.004463 0.002861
2 0.0005 0.003265 3.05e-05 0.0003662 0 0.001709 0.005798 0.004395 0.002808
3 0.0010 0.003332 2.54e-05 0.0003052 0 0.001704 0.005671 0.004400 0.002823
4 0.0015 0.003313 2.18e-05 0.0002616 0 0.001678 0.005689 0.004447 0.002921
5 0.0020 0.003313 2.18e-05 0.0002834 0 0.001591 0.005646 0.004360 0.003008
6 0.0025 0.003488 2.18e-05 0.0002180 0 0.001657 0.005580 0.004338 0.002986
       Al N       Cr        Ni Mo       Cu       V    Nb.2     Ti        B Zr
1 0.02148 0 0.004768 0.0003052  0 0.003700 0.03910 0.06409 0.1157 0.004654  0
2 0.02155 0 0.004578 0.0002441  0 0.003601 0.03897 0.06406 0.1158 0.004700  0
3 0.02164 0 0.004603 0.0003306  0 0.003611 0.03886 0.06406 0.1159 0.004705  0
4 0.02171 0 0.004621 0.0003488  0 0.003597 0.03889 0.06404 0.1158 0.004752  0
5 0.02180 0 0.004643 0.0003488  0 0.003619 0.03895 0.06383 0.1159 0.004752  0
6 0.02175 0 0.004469 0.0002616  0 0.003510 0.03889 0.06374 0.1159 0.004621  0
  Ca H       Co       Mg     Pb.2        W Cl     Na.3      Ar
1  0 0 0.008240 7.63e-05 0.003891 0.004501  0 0.001335 0.01175
2  0 0 0.008026 6.10e-05 0.003876 0.004425  0 0.001343 0.01157
3  0 0 0.008036 5.09e-05 0.003815 0.004501  0 0.001246 0.01155
4  0 0 0.008022 4.36e-05 0.003815 0.004578  0 0.001264 0.01144
5  0 0 0.008000 4.36e-05 0.003771 0.004643  0 0.001351 0.01142
6  0 0 0.008131 4.36e-05 0.003771 0.004708  0 0.001243 0.01125
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why I have to skip the first 2 lines? And why doesn´t this wirk in read.csv directly?

Comment: @user590885: you are right, `skip=2` can be omitted (I edited my answer based on that), the second, blank line will be skipped. You can also use the `read.csv` function to read this file (with the same paramateres given), but as your file is not delimited by commas, but tabulators instead, I do not think it would be pretty. Look for `?read.table` for details about the similarities of the functions (the differences can be found in the defaults).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the *readr*-package, you may also choose to use *stringi::stri_enc_detect2*. This function is particularly efficient if the locale is known and if you are dealing with some form of UTF or ASCII: "..it turns out that (empirically) *stri_enc_detect2* works better than the ICU-based one [*stringi::stri_enc_detect* used by the *guess_encoding*] if UTF-* text is provided."

[Details on stringi::stri_enc_detect](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.2.2/topics/stri_enc_detect).

[Details on stringi::stri_enc_detect2](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.2.2/topics/stri_enc_detect2).

[Change-request for guess_encoding](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/861)

Answer (score 2):

@enrique-pérez-herrero answer is great. With `guess_encoding("your_file", n_max = 1000)` you will get the most likely encodings. Then you can read the file using that encoding: `readr::read_csv(file_path, locale = locale(encoding = "ENCODING_CODE"))`

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a function that tries to read the file with all the potential encodings and outputs a list with two data frames:

- Nested data frame with the content of the file in all the working encodings
- The data frame with the most likely one.

---

```
detect_file_encoding <- function(file_path) {
  
  library(cli)
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  library(readr)
  library(stringi)
  
  
  # Read file in UTF-8 and detect encodings present
  file_raw = readr::read_file(file_path, locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
  encodings_found = stringi::stri_enc_detect(file_raw)
  
  # Function to read the file using all the encodings found
  try_all_encodings <- function(file_path, ENCODING) {
    
    FILE = read_file(file_path, locale = locale(encoding = ENCODING))
    HAS_BAD_CHARS = grepl("\u0086", FILE)
    
    if (!HAS_BAD_CHARS) {
      tibble(encoding = ENCODING, 
            content_file = list(FILE))
    } else {
      tibble(encoding = ENCODING, 
             content_file = list("BAD_CHARS detected"))
    }

  }

  # Safe version of function  
  try_all_encodings_safely = safely(try_all_encodings)
  
  # Loop through all the encodings
  OUT = 1:length(encodings_found[[1]]$Encoding) %>% 
    purrr::map(~ try_all_encodings_safely(file_path, encodings_found[[1]]$Encoding[.x]))

  # Create nested clean tibble with all the working encodings and contents 
  OUT_clean = 1:length(OUT) %>% purrr::map(~ OUT[[.x]]$result) %>% dplyr::bind_rows() %>% dplyr::left_join(encodings_found[[1]] %>% dplyr::as_tibble(), by = c("encoding" = "Encoding"))
   
  # Read file with the most likely working encoding
  DF_proper_encoding = suppressMessages(readr::read_csv(file_path, skip = 12, locale = locale(encoding = encodings_found[[1]]$Encoding[1]), show_col_types = FALSE, name_repair = "unique"))

  # Output list
  OUT_final = list(OUT_clean = OUT_clean,
                   DF_proper_encoding = DF_proper_encoding)
  
  # Output message
  cli::cli_alert_info("Found {nrow(OUT_clean)} potential encodings: {paste(OUT_clean$encoding)} \n - DF_proper_encoding stored using {OUT_clean$encoding[1]}")
  
  return(OUT_final)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This file has UTF-16LE encoding with BOM (byte order mark). You probably should use `encoding = "UTF-16LE"`

Comment: For completeness of this answer: in `read.table` proper parameter is `fileEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

My tidy update to @marek's solution, since I'm running into the same problem in 2020:

```
#Libraries
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

#Make a vector of all the encodings supported by R
encodings <- set_names(iconvlist(), iconvlist())
#Make a simple reader function
reader <- function(encoding, file) {
  read.csv(file, fileEncoding = encoding, nrows = 3, header = TRUE)
}
#Create a "safe" version so we only get warnings, but errors don't stop it
# (May not always be necessary)
safe_reader <- safely(reader)

#Use the safe function with the encodings and the file being interrogated
map(encodings, safe_reader, `<TEST FILE LOCATION GOES HERE>`) %>%
  #Return just the results
  map("result") %>%
  #Keep only results that are dataframes
  keep(is.data.frame) %>%
  #Keep only results with more than one column
    #This predicate will need to change with the data
    #I knew this would work, because I could open in a text editor
  keep(~ ncol(.x) > 1) %>%
  #Return the names of the encodings
  names()
```