# Weird characters appearing in text column in R

Tags: r

I am transferring a CSV file over from Excel in R. One of my columns contains text for each observation but ends up showing up in the following way:

```
"Hey! \x8c\xe6 Maybe I can give some suggestions: \x8c\xe6"
```

What's going on with the `\x8c\xe6`? Is there anyway I can do something so that I only have `A-Z,a-z`, and characters such as `.,+/\?*()` etc.

Comment: This is due to incorrectly specified encoding. You can specify the encoding when saving from Excel. Save As -> Tools -> Web Options -> Encoding. Probably set this to utf-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about removing all non-printable characters with `gsub`

```
a <- "Hey! \x8c\xe6 Maybe I can give some suggestions: \x8c\xe6"
gsub("[^[:print:]]","",a)

# [1] "Hey!  Maybe I can give some suggestions: "
```

The `[:print:]` class and others are defined on the `?regex` help page.

Answer (score 1):

That's an encoding error, I've gotten those a lot in R (see this [encoding table](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8960&number=128&names=2&utf8=string-literal) to get a sense of the translation issue). I did this totally inefficient thing where I would use 'gsub' for the errors I could see, simply deleting them:

```
gsub('\\x8c\\xe6', '', data)
```

However, this post may help in detecting the correct encoding: [How to detect the right encoding for read.csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv)