# R script to check the encoding of a file

Tags: r

I read my file in an R scrip function using read() function .I believe sessionInfo() just gives  the info about the R studio settings and not the encoding type of file read.

How do i check if the file is encoded in say UCS-2LE?

Comment: http://www.r-studio.com/Mac_Help/r-studio_settings.htm

Comment: This previous question might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv

Comment: thanks that helped:-)!