# Encoding for read.csv: data is truncated and special characters are not read properly

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8, import

I want to read a csv file with 5.000 observations into `R Studio`. If I set the encoding to `UTF-8`, only 3.500 observations are imported and I get 2 warning messages:

```
# Example code
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
df <- read.csv("path/data.csv", dec = ".", sep = ",")
```

> 1: invalid input found on input connection
>
> 2: EOF within quoted string

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv) I was able to find some encodings, which are able to read the whole csv file, e.g. `windows-1258`. However, with this encoding special characters such as ä, ü or ß are not read properly.

My guess is, that `UTF-8` would be the right encoding, but that something is wrong with the character/factor variables of the csv file. For that reason I need a way to read the whole csv file with `UTF-8`. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your code and an example CSV? Are you setting `encoding` to `UTF-8` or `fileEncoding` to `UTF-8` or both?

Comment: I updated my post with some example code. I also tried `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"`, but that didn't solve my problem. The file is a normal csv file.

Comment: Try to read the file via `data.table::fread("path/data.csv",verbose=T)`. It will be more enlightening

Comment: Thank you very much @ agerom! That solved the problem.