# Non-existing blank/strange character at the beginning of the import

Tags: r, import, read.table

I have a strange (to me) case:
I am importing a data with read.table (the file is a CSV - a couple of columns, nothing special I believe).
The unexpected behavior is that in the resulting r data frame I receive a strange first character before the first value (first data row) - see `head(data,5)` below

```
            Number
1        п»ї400007
2           400007
3           400007
4           400007
5           400007
```

When I open the data in the viewer it looks like there's a blank character before the first value.
When I open the csv in notepad there is nothing before 400007 in the first row.

This has happened to me a couple of times. 
Now if I want to tell `read.table` function that this "Number" variable should be read as number/integer it gives an error because of this strange character.

Could it be anything related to my language system settings(Windows)?

Any ideas?

Comment: It is probably a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Try saving the file as ASCII first (open in Notepad, Save As, change the encoding).

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476391/i-cant-read-in-data-to-r/17291694#17291694